# How to force Ansible to use sudo to install packages?

Tags: ansible, sudo

I have a playbook than run roles, and logs in the server with a user that has the sudo privileges. The problem is that, when switching to this user, I still need to use `sudo` to, say, install packages.

ie:

```
sudo yum install httpd
```

However, Ansible seems to ignore that and will try to install packages without `sudo`, which will result as a fail.

Ansible will run the following:

```
yum install httpd
```

This is the role that I use:

```
tasks:
  - name: Import du role 'memcacheExtension' 
    import_role:
      name: memcacheExtension
    become: yes
    become_method: sudo
    become_user: "{{become_user}}"
    become_flags: '-i'
    tags:
      - never
      - memcached
```

And this is the tasks that fails in my context:

```
- name: Install Memcached
  yum:
    name: memcached.x86_64
    state: present
```

Am I setting the `sudo` parameter at the wrong place? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: This should be on https://superuser.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you specify "become_user", the task will be executed as this user. No matter if this user has sudo rights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up specifying Ansible to become root for some of the tasks that were failing (my example wasn't the only one failing, and it worked well. The tweak in my environment is that I can't login as root, but I can "become" root once logged in as someone else.

Here is how my tasks looks like now:

```
- name: Install Memcached
  yum:
    name: memcached.x86_64
    state: present
  become_user: root
```

Comment: I was having the same problem installing a package with apt, and even though I wrote become true at the beginning of my playbook, for some reason it doesn't work inside tasks. I had to write become_user root after name.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify become: yes a few places. Often it is used at the task level, sometimes it is used as command line parameter (--become, -b run operations with become). It can be also set at the play level:

```
- hosts: servers
  become: yes
  become_method: enable
  tasks:
    - name: Hello
  ...
```

You can also enable it in group_vars:

group_vars/exmaple.yml

```
ansible_become: yes
```

For your example, using it for installing software I would set it at the task level. I think in your case the import is the problem. You should set it in the file you are importing.

Answer (score -4):

Use shell module instead of yum.

`- name: Install Memcached
  shell: sudo yum install -y {{ your_package_here }}`

Not as cool as using a module, but it will get the job done.

Your become_user is ok. If you don't use it, you'll end up trying to run the commands in the playbook, by using the user used to stablish the ssh connection (ansible_user or remote_user or the user used to execute the playbook).

Comment: Why would you use "sudo" if Ansible offers "become" and can select from the different methods available? In fact, Ansible should emit a warning if you do that.

Comment: For what i understood, he is already using become, but the user he becomes to, still needs to use "sudo". So the only way i could imagine was to keep using the become he is already using, and on top of that run it with shell module. Warning is not a problem, you can always disable it either with args in the task or directive in ansible.cfg. Maybe I'm missunderstood what op is asking?

Comment: Using the right module isn't about being cool; it's about using the tool properly. If you just drop down the shell each time, then there's little point in using ansible in the first place, as opposed to just using your own shell script. If the become_user needs to sudo, then the become_user needs to be set to root or some user that doesn't have to sudo.