# how to become root in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

trying to run a very simple playbook, by the docs. The script is meant to install docker and has its own hosts file. So far looks good by the docs, and sort of worked without the become user part.

```
---
- hosts: test
  #remote_user: root
  
  tasks:
  - name: Install Docker.
  become: yes
  become_user: root
    package:
      name: "docker"
      state: "latest"
```

getting this error message:

```
Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  mapping values are not allowed in this context

The error appears to be in '/Users/user1/Documents/ansible/playbook.yml': line 9, column 12, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  become_user: root
    package:
           ^ here
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55285429/how-to-force-ansible-to-use-sudo-to-install-packages) answers the same question you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indentation is wrong:

```
---
- hosts: test  
  tasks:
  - name: Install Docker.
    become: yes
    become_user: root
    package:
      name: "docker"
      state: "latest"
```